# InputMismatchException when reading alphanumeric user input from java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, alphanumeric

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StrinExp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        String a = null;
        System.out.println("Enter username");
        i=scanner.nextInt();
        a=a.valueOf(i);
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

But m getting error when i am giving a alphanumeric value..

ex: Manish0818

and even when i am giving same value as string, still facing the same problem.

Help

Comment: Do you think `Manish0818` is an integer?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: That is i am asking, how i can give a alphanumeric input suppose a username like Manis0818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your input statement.

```
String a = null;
System.out.println("Enter username");
a = scanner.next();
System.out.println(a);
```

If there's an alphanumeric, then take it in as a string, not as an integer.
You will land in an `InputMismatchException` if you do so.
It means that you're trying to take an integer but you are entering a string which differ in data types.

and if you wish to remove all junk characters except alphanumeric then you can try

```
a = a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "");
```

Comment: Well i have already done that previously, do you know how can i do this using regex 
username with special char

Comment: what do you wanna do actually? Replace all special characters in a string or take only alphanumeric characters as input?

Comment: suppose i have a line like "manish@34%#" i want to remove, all special char.. How it can be done ?

Comment: check the answer now @ManishKumar